# When to std::move from *this in ref qualified method?

Tags: c++11, functional-programming, immutability, move-semantics

I am playing around with immutable objects after reading the excellent [Functional Programming in C++](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-c-plus-plus) book. Assume I have a class for an immutable vector like this:

```
template<typename T>
class immutable_vector
{
public:
   immutable_vector() {}

immutable_vector<T> push_back(const T& t) const &
{
    immutable_vector result(*this);
    result.data.push_back(t);
    return result;
}

//What is the best way to implement this? (see below)
immutable_vector<T> push_back(const T& t) &&;

private:
   std::vector<T> data;

};
```

I know that this is a dumb way of implementing the immutable vector, but this is not the point of the question. My question is on how to implement the rvalue qualified member function push_back.

**Variant 1**

```
immutable_vector<T> push_back(const T & t) &&
{
    data.push_back(t);
    return std::move(*this);
}
```

**Variant 2**

```
immutable_vector<T> push_back(const T & t) &&
{
    immutable_vector<T> result(std::move(*this));
    result.data.push_back(t);
    return result;
}
```

This is the way the author of the book does it.

**My Question**

Is one way better than the other or are they completely equivalent?

My guess was that they would be equivalent, because in both cases the move constructor is called once. I would also assume that in Variant 2 copy elision would take place so that no additional constructors would be called. Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps irrelevant, but aren't both variants missing `const`? Shouldn't the signature be `immutable_vector<T> push_back(const T & t) const &&`?

Comment: I thought that using const here would prevent me from mutating the contained vector. Which is what I want to do.

Comment: I see, and why then return a new instance of `immutable_vector<T>`? It mutates, but returns a copy of the mutation. It feels like an utterly confusing interface. The name `immutable` on something that mutates doesn't help.

Comment: I agree that this is not a good immutable vector implementation. But the point of my question was the difference between the variants. I am interested in taking advantage of move semantics for immutable data structures.